# D3 Line chart using category name (string) in x-axis

Tags: d3.js

IN d3 chart, I don't want to use Date in x-axis. I have simple category and count of that category value and I want to create a chart using these value.

I am using the below URL to create the line chart
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245

But in place of year, I want to show the category name in x-axis.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use an ordinal scale instead of a time-scale for the x-axis, have a look at [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304).

Basically replace

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);
...
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
```

with

```
var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);
...
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
```

But it is hard to answer your question without any code examples of what you have tried so far and what you hide. If you provide for example a jsfiddle of your code you will get much better answers and not a question that gets downvoted.

Comment: Thanks cleared for you help. I am using this https://jsfiddle.net/7dwemdLx/8/  jsfiddle example to create the line chart. 
In this example it uses numeric value in x-axis, but I want to show string value in x-axis. Please find below the sample data set to create the line chart.
      var dataset = [
          {x: "A", y: 5},
          {x: "B", y: 8},
          {x: "C", y: 13}  
        ];

Comment: See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7dwemdLx/9/ The only thing i have changed (except for the dataset) is the definition of xScale. In your original question, the link you posted was to d3v4, but in your fiddle you use d3v3, and thats why the my original answer does not work on your fiddle.